# Is it safe (with modern Subversion) to "reintegrate" more than once?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging, svn-merge-reintegrate

If I make a branch `35.1-extra` from the `35.1` branch (release branch obviously), do some work, and then after some time merge stuff from 35.1-extra back into 35.1, is it OK to merge more than once?

I remember this was problematic in old versions of Subversion so whenever I reintegrate, I either created a new branch if I had to do some extra work, or re-created the "extra" branch, and continued working there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had [to keep a reintegrated branch alive](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice) with Subversion 1.7 and older clients. Thanks to the new ["automatic reintegration merge"](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate) feature in Subversion 1.8 release, so called "keep-alive dance" is no longer necessary:

- `svn merge` automatically detects whether reintegration merge has to be done,
- `--reintegrate` option of `svn merge` is deprecated in SVN 1.8+.

Comment: Yep, that is basically what guys from the IRC #svn channel told me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this old problem has been fixed in Subversion 1.8 - http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate .